# What 1990's scifi book was about a fighter pilot who meets an alien race and averts war with them?

Tags: story-identification

Not a lot to go on, but... I seem to remember a guy in a space fighter going out to meet a fleet of alien invaders and somehow avoiding all out war. I also remember something about the guy having a sister and that she was important to the story. It's not Armor, Ender, or Starship Troopers, but it reminds me of them. I think it came out around the same time as In Conquest Born, Neuromancer, Hardwired, Snow Crash, etc. It may have been hard scifi. I don't think it was cyberpunk, but it might have been.

Comment: Sounds a little like 'Only You Can Save Mankind' by Terry Pratchett, but that's very much NOT hard scifi! He had a female friend (Kirsty) but no sister.

Comment: Sounds something like [The Last Starfighter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Last_Starfighter) which was a 1980's movie but there was a novelization.  Doesn't sound a proper match to what you describe, but maybe.

Comment: @StephenG great book, but not it, it's more recent. The Last Starfighter has all out war and he wins it, IIRC.

Comment: Come to think of it "Guy in space fighter with sister important to plot and stopping a war" sounds rather like "Star Wars".  Search the long list of authors who tried to sue Lucas, maybe. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, the details were a little off, pilot was a girl, not a guy, she wins the battle and defeats  the alien wolfpack. I found it the hard way, looking through a few thousand books in Goodreads lists — Chris Claremont's *[First Flight](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/160861.First_Flight)*.

[image: FirstFlight Cover]

Comment: This is actually what I thought of when I saw the question. Never read it. Probably wouldn't - I've read dozens (if not hundreds) of comics by Claremont, but novel-wise I forced my way through at least 2 (maybe all 3) books in his trilogy placed in the same world as the *Willow* movie. That was an experience I never intend to go through again.